# Give a example where the opposite direction of $\mathbb{E}|X_{n}-X|^{2}\rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow X_{n}\overset{(p)}{\rightarrow} X$ is not available.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Give a example where the opposite direction of $\mathbb{E}|X_{n}-X|^{2}\rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow X_{n}\overset{(p)}{\rightarrow} X$ is not available.

**Remark:** Look online for an example of this situation and I didn't find it, one day I started thinking about it and I found it, I want to share my proposal, another person may need it. If you have another example I would like you to share it here.

**My attempt** We consider $X=0$ and  $X_{n}$ with density function $f_{n}$ where 
$$
f_{n}=\frac{n-1}{n}f_{n}^{(1)}+\frac{1}{n}f_{n}^{(2)}.
$$
where $f_{n}^{(1)}$ is the $\mathrm{Uniform}[0,1/n]$ density and $f_{n}^{(1)}$ is the $\mathrm{Uniform}[n,n+1/n]$ density.

Answer (score 4):

What about $X_n(\omega):= \sqrt{n}1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(\omega).$ with $\Omega = [0,1]$ and the Lebesgue measure?
Then $X_n(\omega) \rightarrow 0$ a.s. and $E[|X_n-0|^2]=1$ for all $n,$ so $X_n$ doesn't converge in $L^2.$ However, $X_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability.